# Convert date string to date (JS)

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, date, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm using moment.js to get a date into the correct format to allow it to be used at the back-end, via ajax.

Here is code of it in View:

```
function todolisttoday(){
   var dateNow = moment().format("DD/MM/YYYY").toDate();
    var model = {
        dateTime:dateNow
   };
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("GetTodayList", "Home")',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        data: JSON.stringify(model),
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        processData: false,
        success: function(data) {
            var list = data;       
        }
    });
};
```

And here is the back-end code:

```
    public JsonResult GetTodayList(DateTime dateTime)
    {
        var items = db.Appointments.Where(x => x.Date == dateTime)
            .Select(x => new
            {
                title = x.Title,
                time = x.Start_appointment
            }).ToList();

        return Json(items, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

I need to have the Date variable to make a select from the database.

I tried to do it like this: `var dateNow = moment().format("DD/MM/YYYY").toDate();` but it does not work.

How can I convert `dateNow` to send it to the back end as a variable that will work?

Comment: What is the actual value your trying to format. Or are you just trying to pass back today's date (in which case, why not just do it on the server) It would just need to be `var items = db.Appointments.Where(x => x.Date == DateTime.Today)`

Comment: Actual value is 26/08/2017. 

in which case, why not just do it on the server -  why not on client-side? @StephenMuecke

Comment: What error message do you get? (check [JqXHR object](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/))

Comment: So , you mean send `get` request and handle date on server side?@StephenMuecke

Comment: What would be the point of sending todays date to the server? And if you wanted to write unnecessary code, then its `var dateNow moment().toISOString();`

Comment: Note also its unnecesary to use `contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',` and `JSON.stringify(model)`. You can just delete `contentType` and use `data: model`

Comment: You're right , handling it on server side was much easier. Thank's @StephenMuecke